# How to use XmlSerializer to deserialize a simple collection into an instance of List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I haven't been able to find a question related to my specific problem.

What I am trying to do is take a list of Xml nodes, and directly deserialize them to a List without having to create a class with attributes.

So the xml (myconfig.xml) would look something like this...

```
<collection>  
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
    <item>item3</item>
    <item>etc...</item>
</collection>
```

In the end I would like a list of items as strings.

The code would look like this.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( List<string> ) );
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create( "myconfig.xml" )
{
    List<string> itemCollection = (List<string>)serializer.Deserialize( reader );
}
```

I'm not 100% confident that this is possible, but I'm guessing it should be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your correction abatishchev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you married to the idea of using a serializer? If not, you can try Linq-to-XML. (.NET 3.5, C# 3 [and higher])

Based on your provided XML file format, this is the simple code.

```
// add 'using System.Xml.Linq' to your code file
string file = @"C:\Temp\myconfig.xml";
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(file);
List<string> list = (from item in document.Root.Elements("item")
                     select item.Value)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Cool alternative. However I think the advantage to the serializer is that I can use it to also save to my configuration if the collection changes. Either way, your example is helpful to me.

Comment: Explore it. You can also use Linq-to-XML to write your XML files. It's a nice tool.

Comment: I will look into this, but at this point I am trying to figure out specifics with the XmlSerializer. For me, it is interesting to know that .Net uses ArrayOfString as a root node for a collection, and the type as element names. Certainly your example is best when loading and reading a simple xml file, but currently my question is centered around the behavior of the XmlSerializer, as it will allow me to be more or less verbose when defining more complex files for Serialization and Deserialization. That is unless you are saying that Linq-to-XML can completely replace the XmlSerializer...?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, interestingly enough I may have found half the answer by serializing an existing List.

The result I got is as follows...

This following code:

```
List<string> things = new List<string> { "thing1", "thing2" };
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>), overrides);
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("things.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, things);
}
```

Outputs a result of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <string>thing1</string>
    <string>thing2</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

I can override the root node by passing an XmlAttributeOverrides instance to the second parameter of the XmlSerializer constructor. It is created like this:

```
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attributes = new XmlAttributes { XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute("collection") };
overrides.Add( typeof(List<string>), attributes );
```

This will change "ArrayOfString" to "collection". I still have not figured out how to control the name of the string element.

Answer (score 1):

To customize List element names using XmlSerializer, you have to wrap the list.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="", ElementName="collection")]
public class ConfigWrapper
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<string> Items{ get; set;}
}
```

Usage:

```
   var itemsList = new List<string>{"item1", "item2", "item3"};
   var cfgIn = new ConfigWrapper{ Items = itemsList };
   var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigWrapper));
   string fileContent = null;

   using (var sw = new StringWriter())
   {
        xs.Serialize(sw, cfgIn);
        fileContent = sw.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine (fileContent);
   }

   ConfigWrapper cfgOut = null;
   using (var sr = new StringReader(fileContent))
   {
        cfgOut = xs.Deserialize(sr) as ConfigWrapper;
        // cfgOut.Dump(); //view in LinqPad
        if(cfgOut != null)
            // yields 'item2'
            Console.WriteLine (cfgOut.Items[1]);
   }
```

Output:

```
// fileContent:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<collection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <item>item1</item>
  <item>item2</item>
  <item>item3</item>
</collection>
```

If you don't want to wrap the list, the DataContractSerializer will allow you to custom name the elements if you subclass it:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "collection", ItemName = "item", Namespace = "")]
public class ConfigWrapper : List<string>
{
    public ConfigWrapper() : base() { }
    public ConfigWrapper(IEnumerable<string> items) : base(items) { }
    public ConfigWrapper(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }
}
```

Usage And Output:

```
   var cfgIn = new ConfigWrapper{ "item1", "item2", "item3" };
   var ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ConfigWrapper));
   string fileContent = null;

   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
        ds.WriteObject(ms, cfgIn);
        fileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine (fileContent);
   }
   // yields: <collection xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><item>item1</item><item>item2</item><item>item3</item></collection>

   ConfigWrapper cfgOut = null;
   using (var sr = new StringReader(fileContent))
   {
        using(var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
        {
            cfgOut = ds.ReadObject(xr) as ConfigWrapper;
            // cfgOut.Dump(); //view in LinqPad
            if(cfgOut != null)
                // yields 'item2'
                Console.WriteLine (cfgOut[1]);
        }
   }
```